# Determine which variable use at runtime in Embedded C

Tags: c, embedded

There are two different makefiles for this firmware that I am working on.
Data Version 1 and Data Version 2. Both versions are using the same file called ble_communication.c in each own make file.

To differentiate between the two versions, we have two variables declared inside ble_communication.c

```
static uint8_t data_version1[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
static uint8_t data_version2[] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

Inside the ble_communication.c file we have a function called

```
uint32_t start_broadcasting(void)
{
send_beacon(OPCODE, 0, /* determine data version here to send at runtime */, key);
}
```

My question is since we are using the same file ble_communication.c for both versions of the build, how can the code select which variable to use for its build during the runtime of the code? If it's Data Version 1, I want it to use data_version1[] and if's is Data Version 2 it uses data_version2[].

I can't use #ifndef switch statements as I am not allowed to use them due to the new design guidelines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, I would prefer to use the `#ifdef`, but here is a workaround for you.

Create two files with the desired data and select the required file at build time, using the makefile.

First, prepare two C files, `ble_communication_data1.c` and `ble_communication_data2.c`. Feel free to choose a clearer name.

Place the required data in each C file, but keep the names the same.

**ble_communication_data1.c**

```c
uint8_t ble_communication_data[5] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

**ble_communication_data2.c**

```c
uint8_t ble_communication_data[5] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

Create a header file to access the data:

**ble_communication_data.h**

```c
extern uint8_t ble_communication_data[5];
```

Modify the `ble_communication.c` so that it uses the common variable name:

```c
#include "ble_communication_data.h"

uint32_t start_broadcasting(void)
{
    send_beacon(OPCODE, 0, ble_communication_data, key);
}
```

Finally, in each of the makefiles, add the correct `ble_communication_data` C file to the list of files to be compiled.

Comment: Hey thanks, heaps for your solution. I will be trying this out tomorrow. I also prefer the #ifdnef solution but the codebase I am working on has over 50k+ lines.

Comment: I do not prefer the #ifdef approach (for data/configurations), but rather a separate configuration from (static) code. It allows you to a) provide a configuration per project (in each project directory) maybe generated by a tool, b) you can more easily compare 2 different configurations, c) separate the configuration into a separate flash area to reprogram separate from code, and d) it doesn't bloat the code base the bigger it gets. Use the #ifdef only for code "features" that are enabled or not, to reduce the code size for not used features.